# How to add a superclass to a class with owlready python?

Tags: python, ontology, restriction, owlready

I'm using owlready to enrich an ontology with property restrictions. As we can see in the owlready documentation, it is possible to define restrictions on properties https://owlready2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/restriction.html#restrictions-on-a-property. The authors explained only how to define classes equivalent to restrictions as illustrated in the following picture.

[class equivalent to a restriction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqfVb.png)

I want to add a restriction to an existing class with owlready (I want to replace the equivalent_to by subClass_of). Is it possible? How can I do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from @Jean-Baptiste, the developer of owlready2

It is possible to add superclasses to an existing class with the following syntax:

```
   Class.is_a.append(SuperClass).
```

The superClass may be a Class or a property restriction, for example

```
   Classe.is_a.append(property.some(Value))
```